# Unity "Assertion failed" error on Instantiate object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I'm try instantiate prefab, prefab successfully instantiated, but Unity throws an error to the console:

> Assertion failed
> UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate<UnityEngine.GameObject> (UnityEngine.GameObject,UnityEngine.Transform,bool)
> SlidePanel:OpenChat () (at Assets/Scripts/UI/Location/SlidePanel.cs:37)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:514)
>
> SlidePanel.cs:37 - Instantiate(chat, UI, false);

The problem has something to do with the custom Loop Vertical Scroll Rect component inside the prefab. If remove it, the error disappears. Elsewhere in the project, this component works fine.

Comment: Without seeing your code hard to tell